# How to fetch 10 10 records in json format using views

Tags: views, services

I am working on views(D7) for providing JSON web services ... I am using **JSON_data_document** module
My question is How to get the data returned from the views in ten,ten records.

Example : consider mysql query

```
select *  from table limit $variable,10 ;
```

so if `$variable is 0` it gives 0 - 10 records
and again when webservice is called (developer passes $variable as 11 ) it should give next ten (11 - 20) records. and so on

Is this possible in drupal using views ?

Is there any special module ?

please help !!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe [Services](http://drupal.org/project/services)? Create views with pager by 10 items per page and read [this article](http://tylerfrankenstein.com/code/android-app-with-drupal-7-services-phonegap-and-jquery-mobile) from 19 punkt - how to fetch your view.

Answer (score 2):

If you append ?page=1 to your views page url you should be able to fetch records 11-20. Make sure your view has paging enabled.

I personally prefer the [Views Datasource](http://drupal.org/project/views_datasource) (Views JSON) module for retrieving JSON information about nodes/users through views. This approach definitely supports ?page=1 when appended to your Views Page Display (JSON Data Document) url path.